What causes me to get the error 'unsupported data type: &[]' with GORM?
I have a query with GORM where I pull an array of integers.
func (db *DB) GetAllTracks(ctx context.Context) ([]TrackMatches, error) {
    var results []TrackMatches
    qry := "select triages.htmltext_structure_hash as htmltext_structure_hash, array_agg(tracks.id) as track_ids from tracks cross join unnest(tracks.triage_ids) as i(item) join triages on triages.triage_id = i.item group by triages.htmltext_structure_hash;"
    if err := db.Raw(qry).Scan(&results).Error; err != nil {
        return results, err
    }

    return results, nil
}

type TrackMatches struct {
    HtmlTextStructureHash string        `json:"htmltext_structure_hash" gorm:"column:htmltext_structure_hash"`
    TrackIds              pq.Int64Array `json:"track_ids" gorm:"column:track_ids"`
}

When I hit the Scan call, I get the error unsupported data type: &[]. How do I fix this?

In my case, I needed to add a type to the pq.Int64Array column, like this:
type TrackMatches struct {
    HtmlTextStructureHash string        `json:"htmltext_structure_hash" gorm:"column:htmltext_structure_hash"`
    TrackIds              pq.Int64Array `json:"track_ids" gorm:"column:track_ids;type:int[]"`
}

